# error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required (I have visual Studio + build tools installed all files and path)

Tags: c++, python-3.x, visual-studio, cython, setuptools

How can I get this to work on windows 11?

Command:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
building 'helloworld' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

What I have tried:

I am running version 3.10 python, I have tried anaconda 3.7 and 3.9 still no luck.  I have install visual studio Build Tools 2022 and Visual Studio Community 2022 all files which is around 200gb as well as added C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0 and C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Vc to path.
I have tried https://github.com/abbodi1406/vcredist/releases/tag/v0.62.0

How can I get this to work?

Comment: following this tutorial: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html

Comment: This is just a guess (know very little about python). Although you have VS installed you are not running in the VS environment. Go to Start Menu/Visual Studio 2022/Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022 and try running those commands from there.

Comment: @john Yeah that still gives same issue.  I am assuming there is a pathing issue because I clearly have the files downloaded

Comment: Cythonizing githubtest.pyerror: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/